# Text Style behind an Image or Pic

Tags: images

There are times that surfers block images just to have a faster browsing
(Block download images)

I would like to have an option when this happen to show  a style text
with a large text in colors.

So if the user block my images they still can see my main message.

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a local (to the user) browser setting you have no way of knowing if the image is being displayed or not, and therefore no programatic basis on which to display the style.

If the image is blocked then the alt text will display in your main body text style, this should be sufficient for users to get your message.